# Witcher 3 why are certain herbs grey when looting

Tags: the-witcher-3

I noticed that certain herbs and even some other items are grey when looting like when you are looting a book that you already read. Check the picture [image]

Anyone know why this is? I thought it might be that I won't have any use of that herb in crafting/alchemy, but that is not the case since I see that I can still use such herbs for crafting new potions.

Comment: What exactly is grey here, and what should it be normally?

Comment: @Joachim the picture of the item is not bright as usual

Comment: But are you talking about the name that is grey or something else? And, if it is the name, that seems like standard behaviour.

Comment: @Joachim literally the icon of the item is greyed out a bit, like a book is once it has been read at least once